# Missing QGIS raster menu tools with error'"osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing'?

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, osgeo, osx

I recently had to reinstall QGIS (version 2.2.0-9) and the raster menu is missing its tools. I understand that the GdalTools plugin must be installed and enabled. I have already installed the GDal complete framework package. When I try to load the Gdal Tools plguin, the following error message occurs:

[image]

A similar error message occurs when I go to 'manage and install plugins' and try to reinstall the openlayers plugin. The following message occurs:

[image]

Does anyone know how to install the "osgeo [python-gdal]" module mentioned?

I am using MacOsx 10.8.5.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you use the QGIS version of [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)

Have you installed the required packages ?

- The [GDAL complete package](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete)
- ....

If you did, the `osgeo` module is in:

> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages (or /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Python/2.7/site-packages

And there is a Python path configuration file (.pth) pointing to the module in:

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gdal-py2.7.pth (or /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/**gdal-py2.7.pth**)

The content of this file is:

```py
import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages')
```

or

```py
import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Python/2.7/site-packages')
```

To control, open the Terminal.app and type:

```py
$ python
 ......
 >>> import osgeo
 >>> osgeo.__file__
 '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.pyc'
```

or the same in the Python console of QGIS

After, in the GDALTools parameters:

- for binaries, put: */Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/usr/bin*
- for the path of the Python modules, put */Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.T/site-packages* (or 1.10)
- for the help files, put */Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Resources/doc/gdal* (or 1.10)

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/99841/6725 for explanation on a small flaw in current GDAL Complete installation. After fixing that, everything in this answer is spot on.