# QGIS says "osgeo [python-gdal]" isn't installed on Mac?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, mac, framework

I know similar questions have been asked (like [Missing QGIS raster menu tools - '"osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98480)) -- but I'm encountering a unique problem. I installed GDAL complete 1.11 from [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks), but when I open QGIS, I get the following error message:

[image: screen shot]

Interestingly enough, when I look at the Libraries directory in Finder, there isn't a subfolder called Frameworks. Which tells me something went wrong.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a small flaw in the GDAL Complete install for 1.11. You can fix it yourself by editing the following file:

```
 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gdal-py2.7.pth
```

and verify the contents are:

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages')
```

If it is still referencing the **1.10** install, which you may not have, change it to **1.11** and save the file. You will probably need admin rights to do this. Programs like BBEdit and TextWrangler (free) can handle the file permissions.

See: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Install-problem-on-OS-X-10-9-td5143122.html

Comment: Note: this flaw has been fixed since GDAL 1.11 Complete 2014-05-30.