# QGIS GRASS plugin missing!

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, mac

I just installed QGIS version 2.2.0-Valmiera on my mac with OS X. First I installed all required frameworks. QGIS is running, but the GRASS plugin is not existing. In the toolbox the GRASS tools are there. Any one got an idea how to get the GRASS plugin running?

Comment: Did you check GRASS plugin in Plugin Manager, i.e. enable it? The toolbox is for the Processing plugin, and the GRASS algorithms there are unrelated to the GRASS plugin. However, both use the same GRASS 6.4.3 install, which is bundled within the Kyngchaos.com QGIS.app for 2.2 release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the Plugin Manager and there is no Grass Plugin/field to enable. It is just not there.

Comment: Hmm. This is odd. You will need to provide more details about your OS and exactly the steps that you have done to install QGIS from Kyngchaos.com.

Comment: I have OS X 10.9.3 and followed the instructions on Kyngachaos. So installed the GDAL complete version 1.11. Then installed Matplotib Python Modul and afterwards QGIS 2.2.0?!

Comment: There is an issue with the latest GDAL.framework python setup. See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/99841/6725, and apply the fix to the gdal-py2.7.pth file. See if that helps; regardless it is a required fix for now.

Comment: I'm sorry but i checked it and seems to be alright. Still no Grass Plugin, any ideas left? I'm thankful for the help as I have no idea what's wrong!

Comment: Maybe contact the packager?

Comment: I also have the same problem! I with Windows8. I had QGIS 2.8.2 and I had the Grass plugin. Now I upgraded QGIS to 2.10 and the plugin is missing...

Comment: Did you check out recent versions? e.g. https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-pr.dmg