# Fixing broken gdal-tools plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, osx

I have QGIS installed on my 2011 macbook pro and I recently upgraded my OS to 10.9. After the upgrade, I noticed that QGIS gives me this error (see attachment 1) saying that the plugin is not installed (but it is; the second screenshot shows that it is "local only"). I suppose I can re-install the plugin but I'm hoping that it isn't necessary. Can someone provide some guidance as to how to get the plugin working again? Is it going to require that I completely remove the plugin and re-install?

[image: Attachment 1 showing error message at startup]

[image: Attachment 2 showing dialog from plugins menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the error message you have to install 'python-gdal' bindings. Also you may check out similar questions:

- [Missing QGIS raster menu tools - '“osgeo python-gdal” module is
  missing'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98480/missing-qgis-raster-menu-tools-osgeo-python-gdal-module-is-missing),
- [QGIS says “osgeo python-gdal” isn't installed on
  Mac](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98511/qgis-says-osgeo-python-gdal-isnt-installed-on-mac)

Comment: I ended up re-installing several of the frameworks (newer versions of everything) and got it working. Your links had some good information though. Thanks!